# How do I tag all my friends in a Facebook photo album?

Tags: facebook, photos, album

I have uploaded several photos to Facebook with friends in them and want to tag them all.

How do I tag all my friends to a particular album?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to do it manually....

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of an update as to how you can achieve this.

Go to the album. And select the friend/page you want to tag.

[image: Example of a tagged entity]

Now start clicking away on the photos, if you don't care where in the photo it is tagged you can iterate through a lot of photos this way.

Repeat for the rest of the friends.

This is tad faster than the original flow of tagging while uploading.

Otherwise you can also create an event/trip and add the album to it.

[image: Life Event]

The third way which does not explcitly tag the friends within your album but the album itself is to go album in the timeline and then tag your friends.

[image: Tag your friends from within the timeline]

Answer (score 1):

You should make a list with all your friends in. Then you can tag the list rather than each individual friend.